# How to play several sounds one by one in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have several sounds, how can I play them one by one. When I just use play(), the sounds play simultaneously. I also tried to handle SOUND_COMPLETE event, but it doesn't work.

```
sampleMP3A.play().addEventListener(
    Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,
    function(event:ResultEvent, o:Object):void {
        sampleMP3B.play();
});
```

sampleMP3A plays well, but sampleMP3B doesn't play.

Comment: Generally, create an instance of the Sound class ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html ) for each sound and use the "play()" method. What have you tried; and why didn't it work?

Comment: I mean, I want to play the first sound and then play the second sound. When I just use play() one by one, the sounds play simultaneously.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Or does it just do nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
             private var sounds:Array // it contain your sounds.


        private var ind:Number = 0;

        private function playSounds():void
        {
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(sounds[ind]);
            var s:Sound = new Sound(req);
            var soundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel;
             soundChannel = s.play();
             soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,onComplete);
        }


        private function onComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            ind++;
            playSounds();
        }
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it do work. Seems like I should use a channel to handle event. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about if you want to change songs before it's finished playing?

Comment: just call playSound() and change corresponding sound array index